# Variables not displaying correctly

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I am using `user_data[TO] = update.message.text` to update variables as a user types information into the bot.

When it comes time to output those variables, it is only showing sequential numbers starting at 0.

```
FROM, TO, SEND, REVIEW = range(4)
user_data = {}
```

I am using this to store the variables.
and this to output them.

```
def review_handler(update: Update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('*Review your Details* \n\n'
                                f'Data1 \+{FROM} \n'
                                f'Data2 \+{TO} \n\n'
                              'Press /yes to proceed and /cancel to exit', parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

I am getting output like Data1 +0 Data2 +1
and so on. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to use `{user_data[TO]}` instead of just `[TO]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).